# npx create-react-app my-app not responding

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to run **npx create-react-app my-app** in Ubuntu and it doesn't respond at all rather just keeps the terminal engaged unless I cancel via **Ctrl+C**

[Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv5d6.png)

I have removed and reinstalled node and npm.

Node: v18.18.2
npm: 9.8.1
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the name of your project to the CL in the image you are showing.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

instead of:

```
npx create-react-app
```

Comment: I'm using ./ which installs it in the current directory but regardless it doesn't respond eve with npx create-react-app my-app.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was fixed by downgrading from node18 to 16.